# like plug-in button turns its label to share when liked

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

The button works but when I click to like the label turns to "share". This is my button:

```
<div data-href="http://facebook.com/Fitnoss" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" class="fb-like"></div>
```

And this is my SDK call & init:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    channelUrl: "/fbc.html",
    cookie: true,
    logging: true,
    status: true,
    xfbml: true
  });
};

(function(d) {
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

I'm using the brazilian portuguese SDK!

Does anyone knows or have any idea why this happens?